# migrating from ASP.NET profiles in website to web application project (cannot handle propertygroups)

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am transfering my solution from a website project to a web application project. In the process I am migrating profiles as well. Part of migrating from website to web application is that I need to write my own Profile-class as described here: http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/

This works fine for all my existing properties except those belonging to a propertygroup.
In my website I had a propertygroup called "Facebook" for storing facebook-specific details. But in my web application project I cannot access these properties. Instead it seems to overwrite my existing properties with new empty ones. When I look in the database I can see that the old properties were stored as eg. "Facebook.FacebookUserId" whereas the new properties are stored as just "FacebookUserId" (without the "Facebook"-prefix). So my question is how to get my old properties ? I have tried creating propertygroups as proposed in the link above, but this just leads to a new xml-property (serializing the class).

Right now I am fetching the properties like this:
    public long FacebookUserId
    {
     get
       {
        return (long)GetPropertyValue("FacebookUserId");
       }
    }

I have also tried:
    public long FacebookUserId
    {
     get
       {
        return (long)GetPropertyValue("Facebook.FacebookUserId");
       }
    }

But none of this seems to work.

Any help is appreciated

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a search and replace on the Facebook-prefix, and removed it